# Is there a VBA code to protect reference between two files when they are moved from user to user?

Tags: excel, vba, reference

Say there is 'File 2.xlsm' that feeds from worksheets in 'File 1.xlsm'. These 2 files will be moved back and forth among multiple users. The name of 'File 1.xlsm' will change whenever it is updated. I'm afraid their new locations will break the VBA macros. How can the reference between 2 files be protected?

Comment: store the files on a network shared drive so users do not need to move them around.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman What if the name of File 1 name changes? Is there a macro for a permanent reference between the 2 files?

Comment: No. There is no such thing. You need to ask user to re-link file in that case. You can do that through VBA, but I don't think it's such an elegant solution.